# How to print a file after writing to it in Python

Tags: python

I am  following Hard to Learn Python the Hard way and have tried to modify exercise 17 where you copy one file (Doc1.txt) to another (Doc2.txt) but it is not working using the code below. If I omit line 11, the file copying works fine, however, when I try to print out the contents of the "new" Doc2 by including line 11, I get the error "IOError: File not open for reading". I feel like I am missing something very basic here and getting a bit frustrated. I know a similar question has been asked before but that answer didn't help. Many thanks in advance.

```
from sys import argv

script, from_file, to_file = argv

in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print out_file.read()

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

Comment: The problem is exactly what the error tells you. You're trying to read a file that's opened for writing only. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening out_file with the 'w' flag which is for write only. You either need to close it, and reopen with 'r' or just open it with 'r+' for read and write from the start

Change

`out_file = open(to_file, 'w')`

to

`out_file = open(to_file, 'r+')`

And then add the following to go back to the start of the file

`out_file.seek(0)`

Answer (score 0):

The file is open for writing only. Set the `"w"` parameter to `"r+"` to read and write.

As well as this,  after writing to the file, the `out_file` position will be at the end of the file. To read the contents, you must first add the line `out_file.seek(0)` to get to the start of the file.